# What's a good way to show parts of an element but hide the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wanting to have a javascript (jQuery) function that removed everything that didn't have the `safe` class.

The problem is, if the parent element is hidden, it cannot show the 'safe' part of it.

Is there a simple way to get around this? I'd rather not go in and `span` all of the elements that need removed.

```
trimmer = function(element){
    x = $(element+' *:not(.safe)');
    x.hide();   
}
trimmer('section');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDMYC/)**

Comment: Seems like you have to show all parents that contain anything that is safe, yes?  So first apply $(".safe").parents().addClass("safe"), then run your trimmer function.

Comment: This will be impossible in your example since you will always have to hide one of the parents of your "safe" `span` if you want to hide the part "Only part of this should be ". This way your span will be hidden, too. In order to only show "visible" you have to change your html structure or take elements of the flow by using `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`

Comment: Hmm.. now wait a minute. What if I add code so everything that isn't `safe` inside gets wrapped in a `disappear` label.. hmmm...

Comment: If you wrap parent nodes that would be possible. In your case you'd wrap "Only part of this should be " in e.g. a `span` adding a class `disappear`. This way the two nodes become siblings and won't affect each other anymore when hidden.

Comment: Right. Now to figure out how to `<span class="disappear">` all of the non-`safe` regions of the parent node...

Comment: You could do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ZDMYC/1/ You still have to put the parts back together though

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = 'section';

//finds all non `.safe` elements in `section`s and hides them
$(':not(.safe)', element).hide();  

//finds all `.safe` elements in `section`s and shows the `section`s
$('.safe', element).parents(element).show();
```

Comment: Neither answer works. Anyone know a way to dissect each element and add spans around everything that isn't `safe`?

Answer (score 0):

Horen was right, it is indeed impossible to show parts of a hidden element.

**To make only parts of the text disappear, the non-`safe` content must be labeled for removal.**

```
$(element).contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3)
    $(this).wrap('<span class="disappear" />');
});
```

You can read more about this answer here:
[How to add spans to all areas of a node that isn't restricted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521059/how-to-add-spans-to-all-areas-of-a-node-that-isnt-restricted/18521156?noredirect=1#18521156)