# How to add spans to all areas of a node that isn't restricted

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a continuation of [What's a good way to show parts of an element but hide the rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520811/whats-a-good-way-to-show-parts-of-an-element-but-hide-the-rest?noredirect=1#comment27236270_18520811)

```
<h1>
  Let's say you had this <span class="safe">text</span>.
</h1>
```

How could one wrap all non-`safe` regions in an element with a `disappear` class (with jQuery).

**Final Output**

```
<h1>
  <span class="disappear">Let's say you had this </span>
  <span class="safe">text</span>
  <span class="disappear">.</span>
</h1>
```

That way, the `parent node` is still visible, but the non-`safe` regions disappear, leaving the `safe`.

I'm not sure how to do this, but surely it's possible.

Answer (score 6):

Text nodes have a `nodeType` of 3. Iterate the nodes and use `wrap()` to wrap the text nodes.:

```
$someElement.contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3)
        $(this).wrap('<span class="disappear" />');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SnjnJ/

Answer (score 5):

Filter the textNodes and wrap them in spans :

```
$('h1').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span class="disappear" />');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k66ZQ/2/)

Comment: @JasonP - Thanks, it's basically the same, just iterates with filter() instead of each().

Answer (score 2):

```
$('h1').children().not('.safe').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VeSCw/

Answer (score 0):

Match all contents of the `h1` and use `.not()` to remove the `safe` from your selection. Then use `.wrap()` to make them "disappear".

http://api.jquery.com/not/